# An identity with multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

How does one prove the identity
$$
\sum_{\substack{k_1, k_2,\ldots,k_n \geq 0\\\\k_1+2k_2+3k_3+\cdots + nk_n = n}} \frac{(k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n)!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!} = 2^{n-1}?
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: what two contexts?

Comment: The statement cries out for a combinatorial proof, btw.

Comment: @ReinerMartin How do you know the two $n$'s were different? I see nothing pointing to that. In fact, the problem makes less sense now.

Comment: Wait, I'll undo, you're right

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combinatorial proof: take $n$ objects arranged in a line. We count the ways to put dividers between adjacent objects. As there are $n-1$ places to put these, the total number of ways is $2^{n-1}.$

Now how many of these arrangements leave $k_1$ groups of single objects, $k_2$ groups of 2 objects, etc.? This is what the multinomial
$$
\frac{(k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n)!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}
$$
counts. Clearly, the total number of objects is $k_1+2k_2+3k_3+\cdots + nk_n,$ which thus must agree with $n.$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: How many ways can you chop a rod of length $n$ into integer pieces?